# hibernate save one to one with master value

Tags: java, hibernate

Want to save a one to one with master value like below.
Have a address class which contains a city class as one to one.
But city is my master values which i dont want to update when i save address.just select the city from dropdown in UI and set the object as it is to address and save the address.but while saving getting below error.

org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.app.fd.entity.Address.city -> com.app.fd.entity.City

```
@Entity
public class Address extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CONTACT_SEQ_GEN")
@SequenceGenerator(name="CONTACT_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "CONTACT_SEQ", allocationSize=5)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Size(max = 50)
@NotNull
private String address1;

@Size(max = 50)
private String address2;

@Size(max = 15)
@NotNull
private String state;

@Size(max = 10)
@NotNull
private String pin;

@Size(max = 255)
private String landmark;

private Boolean deleted;

@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id", insertable=false,updatable=false)
private City city;

}


@Entity
public class City {

/**
 * 
 */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Size(max = 30)
@Column(name = "name",unique = true)
private String name;

@Size(max = 5)
@Column(name = "code",unique = true)
private String code;
}




repository.save(address); // TransientPropertyValueException error
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are saving the `Address` entity with unsaved/detached `City` entity. To fix this issue you make use of cascadeType.ALL, but in your case you don't want to modify the city object. You can use the following approach.

```
City cityFromUI = new City();
cityFromUI.setId(id); //get this id from UI. Store city dropdown as key = id and value = cityName
Address myNewAddress = new Address();
myNewAddress.set*()//Set other address fields
myNewAddress.setCity(cityFromUI);
repository.save(address);
```

Using the above code your address will be mapped to the corresponding city and your city will not get updated as you defined `updatable`to `false` in your `Address` entity.